# Erro de Segmentação

Tags: c, falha-de-segmentação

Olá. Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse erro (segmentation fault)? Não sei porque está acontecendo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cel {
    char *palavra;
    int numOcorrencias;
} celula;



int charValido(char c) {
    if (c != '\0' && c != ',' && c != '.' && c != '?' && c != '/' && c != '\\' && c != '<' && c != '>' && c != '!' && c != '=' && c != '-' && c != '|' && c != '[' && c != ']' && c != '(' && c != ')' && c != '{' && c != '}' && c != 39 && c != '"' && c != '`' && c != '~' && c != '@' && c != '#' && c != '$' && c != '^' && c != '&' && c != '*' && c != ';' && c != ':')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}


celula *montaDicVet(char *nomeArq, int *tam) {
    FILE *arquivo;
    celula *vetor;
    char *texto, *p, c;
    int i, j, num;

    i = j = num = 0;
    texto = p = NULL;
    vetor = NULL;

    arquivo = fopen(nomeArq, "r");

    while (1) {
        c = fgetc(arquivo);

        if (c == EOF) {
            texto = realloc(texto, ++i);
            texto[i-1] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        if (charValido(c)) {
            i++;
            texto = realloc(texto, i);
            texto[i-1] = c;
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);

    i = 0;

    while (texto[i] != '\0')
        printf("%c", texto[i++]);

    return vetor;
}


int main(int numargs, char **args) {
    celula *vetor;
    int *tam = 0;

    vetor = montaDicVet(args[1], tam);

    printf("%d", *tam);
    return 0;
}
```

Execute da seguinte forma: **./testeEP4 textoPequeno.txt**

O argumento da linha de comando se refere ao arquivo txt com o seguinte conteúdo:

---

*A Escola Politécnica da Universidade de São Paulo (Poli/USP) tem mais de um século de história, formando gerações de engenheiros que têm se destacado não só em suas especialidades profissionais, mas também na vida política do País e na administração de empresas e de órgãos públicos. Fundada em 1893, a então denominada Escola Politécnica de São Paulo foi incorporada à USP em 1934; hoje ela é referência nacional e considerada a mais completa faculdade de Engenharia da América Latina.
A Poli ocupa nove prédios na Cidade Universitária, em São Paulo, num total de 141.500 metros quadrados de área construída. Ali trabalham ou estudam 457  professores, 478  funcionários, 4.500 alunos de graduação e 2.500 alunos de pós-graduação. A Escola está organizada em 15 departamentos, responsáveis pelas atividades de ensino, de pesquisa e de extensão de serviços à comunidade.

Na graduação, são oferecidos 17 cursos,  agrupados em quatro grandes áreas da engenharia: Civil, Elétrica, Mecânica e Química. Desses cursos, 15 são semestrais e dois – Engenharia de Computação e Engenharia Química – têm características que os diferenciam dos demais: eles são organizados em períodos quadrimestrais e realizados em cooperação com empresas.
Na pós-graduação, a Poli oferece dez cursos de mestrado, nove de doutorado e um de mestrado profissionalizante. De 1970 a 2006 foram outorgados cerca de 7.000 títulos, entre mestrado e doutorado, o que coloca a Escola como um dos maiores centros de pós-graduação do País e o maior na área de Engenharia.
A Poli também se destaca na realização de pesquisas científicas e tecnológicas, com as quais contribui para o progresso social e econômico do País e para a modernização, competitividade e qualidade dos produtos e processos das empresas.*

---

Comment: O código é bem confuso, mais complexo do que deveria e tem coisas completamente sem sentido, por exemplo `vetor` não é usado de fato, aí `celula` não deveria existir. Por que não faz de forma mais simples, aí provavelmente o problema desaparecerá sozinho. Pode ser que precise disto tudo, mas no código atual não está usando.

Answer (score 0):

O código é muito ineficiente (um realloc  a cada caracter lido ? wtf ?).
Desconsiderando isso, a causa do erro de segmentação é o uso incorreto de ponteiro.

```
int main(int numargs, char **args)
{
  celula *vetor;
  // int *tam = 0;  // <----
  int tam = 0;

  // vetor = montaDicVet(args[1], tam); // <----
  vetor = montaDicVet(args[1], &tam);

  // printf("%d", *tam); // <-----
  printf("%d", tam);

  return 0;
}
```